# Javascript Open all links on _blank Except

Tags: javascript

I am using this code below to open all links on _blank pages and it works great!

I just have one problem.

How can I make it so a specific link or class is ignored by the script?

Here's the code:

```
<script>
    document.onclick = function (e) {
        e = e ||  window.event;
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if (element.tagName == 'A') {
            window.open(element.href, "_blank", "location=yes");
            return false; // prevent default action and stop event propagation
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: using `tagName` is so specific isn't it? Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: It needed to be Tagname in order to automatically do all links but I can to add an exception somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore specific classes, use the below:

```js
document.onclick = function (e) {
  e = e ||  window.event;
  var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

  if (element.tagName == 'A' && !element.classList.contains('noBlank')) {
    window.open(element.href, "_blank", "location=yes");
    return false; // prevent default action and stop event propagation
  }
};
```

```html
<p>BBC should not be _blank</p>
<a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google</a>
<br />
<a href="http://www.yahoo.co.uk">Yahoo</a>
<br />
<a class="noBlank" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk">BBC</a>
```